# State or observer pattern in object C++

Tags: design-patterns, uml, observer-pattern, class-diagram, state-pattern

I am just a bit confused with the difference between the observer and state pattern. I have been given a project where the client is an airplane on a flight which calculates data for different sensor such as GPS,Speed, Fuel level, And then the data is sent over to the network and then to the server. At the moment I have used the observer pattern for my class diagram. The class diagram can be viewed from the below, please let me know if my solution is correct and if the design pattern chosen is good for this solution. [image: Class Diagram]

Comment: It looks like you have misunderstood the Observer pattern in some ways. The component that is updated (in your case the speed, gps, engineFuel, etc) is known as the *Observable* or the *Subject* and the component that wants to know about updates to the *Subject* is known as the *Observer*.

Answer (score 3):

> I am just a bit confused with the difference between the observer and state pattern

The **Observer** pattern is mostly used when you have an object or a set of objects (known as the Observers) that want to be informed/updated about any changes in the state of one or more objects (known as the Observables or Subjects). In your example, the `Network` is the *Observer* that wants to know about the changes in the Airplane data. On the other hand, the Airplane data objects such as `Speed`, `GPS` etc are the *Observable* or *Subjects* that the `Network` wants to keep a track for changes. (Your terminologies seem to be reversed). Whenever the Airplane data such as its `Speed` changes, the `Network` must be notified about this change by the corresponding *Speed* object.

The **State** pattern on the other hand is mostly used when your use case can be represented as a finite state machine. In your example, the entire take off, flying and landing process of the Airplane can be represented in a finite state machine with logical states such as landed, taking off, in flight, landing, etc.

It should now be clear that the *Observer* and *State* pattern both have a valid application in your case with the *Observer* pattern being apt for the main problem statement that you have described in your question. That said, there is no need to have seperate *Observable* objects such as speed, GPS, et.c. You can have a single *Observable* object called `FlighData` which has attributes such as speed, GPS, engineFuelLevel, engineTemp etc.

I would also recommend that you get a better understanding of the *Observer* pattern before you implement it in your application. Here are some links to get started :

- [Observer pattern in C++](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3)
- [Understanding and implementing the Observer pattern in C++](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/328365/understanding-and-implementing-observer-pattern-in)

Answer (score 1):

Make a State-event-action automata to define the system( say for error, interlock or some other checking  condition etc ) - can use the the state design pattern here. 
Observer pattern is used when there is one to many relationship between objects such as if one object is modified, its dependent objects are to be notified automatically. We use observer design pattern when observable does not know the no of observers and should be able to notify other objects without knowing the objects.

Comment: You said, *"Observer pattern is used when there is one to many relationship between objects"*. Not true. You can use the Observer pattern even when you have a single Observable that is being observed by a single Observable. Also, you mention that the state pattern is a better choice without explaining how the example in the original question is better implemented through the state pattern. What components of the given example can be fitted into the state pattern and how? As it stands, you seem to have defined the patterns but not their use in the current context.